# DRY concept, relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hello this is my first post, and i have a little problem, how can i reduce my code? i mean i have @pedidos, @pedidopending and @pedidocomplete how can i reduce it ?? of course each action is independent of other, i mean i dont want to see all in one

```
<% @pedidos.each do |pedido| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= pedido.usuario %></td>
    <td><%= pedido.pedido %></td>
    <td><%= pedido.entrega %></td>
    <td><%= pedido.intermedio %></td>
    <td><%= pedido.status %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', pedido %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pedido_path(pedido) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pedido, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %> 
<% @pedido.each do |pedido| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= pedido.usuario %></td>
    <td><%= pedido.pedido %></td>
    <td><%= pedido.entrega %></td>
    <td><%= pedido.intermedio %></td>
    <td><%= pedido.status %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', pedido %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pedido_path(pedido) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pedido, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. what problem do you have? If it is just a question about code quality, it is better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @PeterSorowka, on the other hand, all the simple questions can be answered from the language documentation. And code quality is what Ruby is all about, so some advanced dicussions will naturally be about code quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
<%[@pedidos, @pedidopending, @pedidocomplete ].each do |paedidos|%>
  <%pedidos.each do |pedido|%>
     <td><%= pedido.usuario %></td>
     ....
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

or

```
<%all_pedidos = []%>
<%all_pedidos.push(*@pedidos).push(*@pedidopending).push(*@pedidocomplete).each do |pedido|%>
  <td><%= pedido.usuario %></td>
   ....
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
<% [@pedidos, @pedido].each do |pedido| %>
  <tr>
    <% [:usuario, :pedido, :entrega, :intermedio, :status].each do |attr| %>
      <td><%= pedido[attr] %></td>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', pedido %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pedido_path(pedido) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pedido, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```